# how to install previous version on TestFlight

Tags: testflight

I want some people install latest version and others install a previous version, so I set the permissions accordingly in hope that user can be automatically directed to the version. However, testFlight always point to latest version and other users will get an error say "You don't have access"...  Anyway from device to install a previous version?

Answer (score 56):

Just follow the steps to install previous version.

1 - Go into testflight

2 - Tap on the app for which you want to get the previous version.

3 - After tapping you will see the detail of it and at the bottom you will see the 'Previous Versions' button.

4 - Tap on 'Previous versions.'

5 - A list will be displayed of all the previous version from where you can install any of the previous version.

Comment: Just to clarify this feature is on the iPhone TestFlight itself and not available in AppStoreConnect/Testflight, at least I was not able to revert to a previous version from there explicitly...

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about splitting versions between testers automatically, but you can download older versions of an app from TestFlight.

On the permissions page for a particular build (from the dashboard, select builds, then select the build of the app you're after—hit the more button next to the latest build to reveal the others) there's a section titled *Share this Build* that provides a direct download link. If it were me, I'd eschew TestFlight's automatic notifications system in this case and send notifications manually, including the appropriate direct link for each tester. If your delivery system allows it, set the email reply address to be the one found on the feedback page for the build and testers can still send feedback by replying to your (now custom) announcement email.

Comment: This is the best (and only) way to do this.

Comment: Yup this is the only way, except on the iPhone 5 with iOS 6 which renders a different web page on safari which allows you to install older builds.

Comment: They just updated their mobile "app" to allow installation of older builds.

Answer (score 5):

I can able to install the previous versions of builds in *TestFlight*. We can upgrade and downgrade to any old/new versions seamlessly

Steps to follow,

1. In TestFlight iOS app
2. Tap on the app for which you want to get the previous version.
3. After tapping you will see the detail of it and at the top, you will
       be able to see the 'Previous Versions' button.
4. Tap on 'Previous versions.'
5. A list will be displayed of all the previous version from where you
   can install any of the previous version.

check the screenshots for more clarify

Comment: Will it loose previous app data?

Comment: No it will not loose the previous data

Answer (score 1):

Just updating this as TestFlight has changed.

From TestFlight, where it shows your App, touch the app icon or tap anywhere in that row on the left side.  That will reveal App Information page.

On the App Information page look for Previous Builds.  If you tap that it will show all of your builds and you can pick one.

Happy coding.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that today is no way to install older builds(

Comment: Were you able to install old version of test flight build?

Comment: Yes, in previous testFlight versions.

Comment: Use another CI tools.

Comment: Do you know any which can overcome this issue?

Comment: I didn't use them, but you can try amazon s3 buckets.

Comment: As of 04/11/2017 TestFlight has the option to install Previous Builds for the application if developer enables and add testflight tester groups with multiple builds enabled from iTunes connect.