# Install old version via TestFlight

Tags: ios, testing, version, testflight

For internal testing we want to install an old version on a device of someone who's UDID is not in the list. Via TestFlight I can add the email of this person in order for him to download the newest version (via internal testing), but I was wondering if it would be possible to enable him to download and install a specific old version?

I've seen this page: [how to install previous version on TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367315/how-to-install-previous-version-on-testflight) but it is rather old and the suggestions are incorrect.

Comment: Were you able to install old build?

Comment: No, when I couldn't find anything myself and got no answer here, I gave up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a workaround to test older builds with TestFlight. You can just use the link provided in the email you received when you uploaded the older build for testing. You will see something like this.

> To test this app, open TestFlight on your iOS device using iOS 8.0 or later and install the update.

Tap on "TestFlight" in the above line. This will open TestFlight with a link to the older build. And you can install it if it hasn't yet expired.

Hope this helps!

**Update**

As of April 11, 2017, TestFlight now supports multiple builds. 
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/

You can navigate to the Previous Builds section of the app in TestFlight and get access to builds which are up to 90 days old.

Comment: In previous builds, I'm not able to see all my builds that are up to 90 days old. Few builds are missing.

Comment: same in my case.

Comment: Retry several times , you will get the older unexpired build.

Answer (score 13):

Latest working way to find previous builds:

- tap on the app icon ( current one )
- scroll to the bottom , you will see 'Previous builds'
- Tap on it and you will see all previous builds.

Thanks

Comment: Not true anymore with new testflight app version

Answer (score 4):

You can check in Testflight application, there is a section old builds, under that section you can see old builds.

Answer (score 0):

In the TestFlight we can check for the old build in that we can select the particular build.
[Please find the screen shot for reference]